# Facebook Activity Feed displaying 'No recent activity to display.'

Tags: facebook

I am trying to incorporate the activity feed box on our website but for some reason, no activities are being displayed. Is there something wrong with this ? I also tried to set 'data-site' attribute with the domain rather than full url, `www.facebook.com/OurFacebookPage` but still does not show any activities.. App id is also correct

```
<div class="fb-activity" 
data-app-id="12345678901234567890" 
data-site="https://www.facebook.com/OurFacebookPage" 
data-action="likes, follow, comments, posts, recommends "
data-width="250px" data-max-age="180" data-colorscheme="light" 
data-header="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Activity Feed plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/activity) shows open graph actions which took place on objects hosted on your site / domain - it's not intended for use with Facebook pages or other content on Facebook.com

If you're using a Facebook page URL with it that's why you're seeing nothing

What you're probably looking for is the [Like Box plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages) which allows users to like your page and shows a feed of recent posts from the page

Comment: I completely did not expect that one! sorry for my stupid question then! I have just looked at the like box and provides something similar to what I was looking  for! Thanks a heaps sir..

Comment: Is it possible to only show the recent posts with the like box? Meaning, hiding the like button and number of likes for the page?

Comment: I don't think so - for something like that you'd need to make a custom solution which pulls the posts from the page via the API and displays them on your site

Comment: ok, well it makes sense. It is called a like-box for a reason I guess! Thanks a heaps, again!